# c++ vector push_back with object pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I need to create a vector of object pointers by having an object passed into this function and then put into a vector of object pointers with push_back, but I'm getting "invalid conversion from const Person* to std::vector::value_type {aka Person*}" How do I pass the pointer to push_back correctly to make this work?

```
vector<Person*>vptr;

void insert(const Person&p)
{
    const Person*ptr=&p;
    vptr.push_back(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You would have to drop the `const` from the function parameter list and pointer declaration:

```
void insert(Person& p)
{
  vptr.push_back(&p);
}
```

or store `const Person*`:

```
vector<const Person*> vptr;
```

Comment: I can't drop the const due to complicated reasons, other stuff is going on in the function. And I can't change the vector type. Is there any other way?

Comment: Why can't you change the vector type?